# Variance Ratio Formula

Tags: optimization, quadratic-form

I've been trying to minimize/maximize the ratio of quadratic forms given by

$$Q(c)=\frac{c^\top \Sigma c}{c^\top \text{diag}(\Sigma) c}$$
where $\Sigma$ denotes a covariance matrix of some $n$-dimensional vector, $X$.

I've been able to show that in the $n=2$ case, $Q(c)$ takes values between $1 \pm R$, where $R$ is the correlation coefficient between $X_1$ and $X_2$. But I'm getting stuck trying to optimize this function in the general case. Is there an analytic solution to this optimization problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right: indeed, there is an algebraic solution.

**The optimization must occur over the set of $c$ for which the denominator is nonzero.**  I will leave to interested readers the special case where there exist nonzero $c$ for which the denominator nevertheless is zero: this is equivalent to at least one of the components of $X$ being constant.

**This leaves us to deal with the generic case where all diagonal elements $\sigma_{ii}^2$ of $\Sigma$ are (strictly) positive.**  Writing

$$\Delta = \pmatrix{\sigma_{11} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \sigma_{nn}}$$

we obtain the usual relationship between the covariance matrix and the [correlation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Correlation_matrices) $R,$

$$\Sigma = \Delta R\Delta.$$

Given $c\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\},$ rescaling $$x = c\Delta \ne 0$$ gives

$$\frac{c^\prime\Sigma c}{c^\prime \operatorname{diag}(\Sigma) c} = \frac{x^\prime R x}{x^\prime x}.$$

Those familiar with [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#First_component) will already see the answer, but for the record let's obtain it using more fundamental results of linear algebra.

Because $\Sigma$ represents a positive-definite quadratic form, so does $R$ and therefore (by the [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case)) $R$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of eigenvectors with associated eigenvalues $\lambda_i\ge 0.$  Use this basis to express $x\ne 0$ as a linear combination

$$x = x_1 e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n.$$

Then
$$\frac{x^\prime R x}{x^\prime x} = \frac{x_1^2\lambda_1 + \cdots +x_n^2\lambda_n}{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$$

is a linear combination of the eigenvalues with coefficients $x_i^2 / (x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2)$ that are not all zero.

This set is (by definition) the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the eigenvalues, which will be the smallest closest interval containing them all.  Clearly **this is maximized by the largest eigenvalue of $R$ and minimized by the smallest one.**

This generalizes the $n=2$ case because the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix with correlation coefficient $r$ are $1\pm r.$

Incidentally, because the eigenvalues are the roots of the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of $R,$ we may consider this  an algebraic solution, even though it's somewhat indirect (you still have to find the roots if you need explicit values).

Comment: @Hasse Thank you--that's correct.  I have made the change.